# Delete the first 8 rows from an SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I delete rows in a SQLite table with this:

```
public void deleteFirstRow()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("eventosUTN", null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String rowId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
        db.delete("eventosUTN", "id" + "=?",  new String[]{rowId});
    }
    db.close();
}
```

I need to delete the first 8 rows when the database has a size bigger than 8 rows, so:

```
public void checkRowsSize(Events events, Context contex)
{  
    new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
        if(events.getRowCount()>8){
            while(events.getRowCount()>8){
                events.deleteFirstRow(contex);
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
}
```

The method Events's getRowCount is:

```
public int getRowCount(){
    String query = "Select*FROM eventsUTN";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

But When I set the while loop in checkRowSize it delete the all database. Why this? But If I set:

```
public void checkRowsSize(Events events, Context contex)
{  
    new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
        if(events.getRowCount()>8){
            events.deleteFirstRow(contex);
        }
    }
}).start();
}
```

It just delete the first row every time the Activity is created, until the database has a size smaller than 8 rows. So without the while loop it works fine!

Comment: How do you define 1st row or first 8 rows? You should use an ORDER BY clause to be sure. There is no order for the rows of a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *delete the first 8 rows when the table has a size bigger than 8 rows* with this statement:

```
delete from eventosUTN
where 
  (select count(*) from eventosUTN) > 8
  and 
  id in (select id from eventosUTN limit 8)
```

where `id` is the `primary key` of your table.
But you should know that what you think as first 8 rows in a table is not always what you get.
Table rows are unordered.
So maybe you should define the logic of this order with the use of an `ORDER BY` clause like:

```
delete from eventosUTN
where 
  (select count(*) from eventosUTN) > 8
  and 
  id in (select id from eventosUTN order by id limit 8)
```

So you can do this in java code like this:

```
String where = "(select count(*) from eventosUTN) > 8 and id in (select id from eventosUTN order by id limit 8)";
db.delete("eventosUTN", where, null);
```

If the `primary key` of your table is `integer` and has been defined as `AUTOINCREMENT` which means that it is always increasing and never reused then you could also use this statement:

```
delete from eventosUTN 
where id < (select id from eventosUTN order by id limit 8, 1)
```

and in java code:

```
String where = "id < (select id from eventosUTN order by id limit 8, 1)";
db.delete("eventosUTN", where, null);
```

Comment: thanks, in that case when deleting the rows from 1 to 8, the new first 8 have the same id that they had before? the id is the primary key and it is autoincrement

Comment: Of course not. This is not how the primary key works. A primary key should not change its value.

Comment: thanks. But when We set "(select id from eventosUTN order by id limit 8, 1)". It select the rows with the primary keys from 1 to 8? or the first 8 rows? Because when we delete the first 8, then the table reach 8 again and it should delete the first new 8 rows

Comment: `select id from eventosUTN order by id limit 8, 1` returns the 1st row after the first 8 smallest ids. 8 is the offset, which means that the statement skips the first 8 and selects the rest but since there is 1 after 8 it selects just 1 row.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any statement to sort the id after removing rows? So there are no gaps in the ids

Comment: No and you should not do that. The primary key is there to identify each row. Its value is irrelevant and the *gaps* should not be considered as gaps. Also as I mentioned in my answer, the last query with the condition: `where id < (select id from eventosUTN order by id limit 8, 1)` should be used only if you have defined the id with the keyword `autoincrement` like `id primary key autoincrement`. If you missed `autoincrement` don't use it but use the 1st query.